# How to convert CSV to TCSV file in python

Tags: javascript, python, csv, type-conversion

A buddy of mine is trying to convert a CSV file full of data into something called a tcsv file for use with a service he is developing.

I could barely find anything on TCSV files except for [here](https://github.com/didip/tcsv) This seems to describe what makes a TCSV file.

So my question is, would I be able to use python, (or JS, as in the example) in order to convert a csv to tcsv file? Is this something I can do with code? If someone could explain what a tcsv file is and how it's used that would help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Tell your buddy the whole point of .csv files is that they are unstructured apart from the commas separating fields and the newlines demarcating new records. 
A clue to how useful the .tscv file extension may be at some future point in time is in the title given by the person on github (your link) experimenting with them: `"Simpler, streamable, more compact, easier to read, gzip friendlier than JSON. Hopefully..."`
If your buddy insists on a more human-readable form of data he can transform them pretty easily into xml, or even JSON, and he'll very likely have more joy than following that github post's apparently aborted experiment.
That tcsv stuff doesn't look easier to read than well-formatted JSON to me. Though xml seems to win hands-down *if written with readability in mind*.
See http://json.org/example.html.

Comment: I believe he needed it in TCSV because he wanted to read it in QGIS, but QGIS takes other data types no? probably XML or something similar im assuming,.